# How can a visitor logged into domain A be spared having to re-log in wherever domain A's widget is installed on other domains?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, cross-domain

Scenario: Mr. Smith joins my site FOO and logs in. Site BAR, on a different domain, has installed my widget. Mr. Smith visits site BAR and is permitted to use the widget only if he is a member of site FOO.

Since many sites can install my widget, how can Mr. Smith be spared the trouble of re-logging in wherever my widget is installed, if he is already logged into site FOO?

Comment: If site BAR makes an AJAX request to your FOO site, the request will be in the context of the logged-in user. Since it is cross-domain I think you'll need JSONP. Get two domains set up on your local machine, and try implementing something - the jQuery AJAX docs will indicate how to make a JSONP request.

Comment: can't do this with jsonp. Needs to be done with CORS enabled ajax in order to use `withCredentials` header to send cookies. Otherwise you have no way to know where request is coming from

Comment: @charlietfl Currently, I have JavaScript installed in remote domains AJAXing PHP with cross-domain activation at my home domain working great. However, adding to my PHP a $_COOKIE["auth"] call doesn't return the value of the auth cookie at my home domain - just "" rather than it value, "44c5d371af9". I am trying to mimic how I imagined Facebook might be doing it with their plugins all over the web not nagging for authentication as long as I'm logged into Facebook.

Comment: they do it using `Oauth` ... basically when you log into any site using facebook, it sends acceptance token back to that sites server , then that site stores token against your user data.